# Spring, Hibernate and .xml Error

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, red5

**ERROR**

```
[INFO] [Launcher:/hibernate] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7d1050be: defining beans [placeholderConfig,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,web.context,web.scope,dataSource,sessionFactory,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,transactionManager,applicationRepository,applicationService,web.handler,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1fb88122
    Exception in thread "Launcher:/hibernate" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/MetadataProvider
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
        at org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader$1.run(TomcatLoader.java:593)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/MetadataProvider
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:400)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:275)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:122)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:78)
        at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
        at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:97)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1443)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/MetadataProvider
        at org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener.initialize(FullTextIndexEventListener.java:151)
        at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners$1.processListener(EventListeners.java:198)
        at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners.processListeners(EventListeners.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners.initializeListeners(EventListeners.java:194)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getInitializedEventListeners(Configuration.java:1338)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1327)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:814)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:732)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
        ... 23 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.MetadataProvider
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
        ... 35 more
```

------------------------------------- and red5-web.xml concerned with this errors..

**CODE**

```
<!-- Wrapper to translate database exceptions into something more friendly -->
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<!-- Hibernate transaction management -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="applicationRepository" class="net.sziebert.tutorials.dao.hibernate.HibernateApplicationRepository">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="applicationService" class="net.sziebert.tutorials.service.impl.ApplicationServiceImpl">
    <property name="applicationRepository" ref="applicationRepository"/>
</bean>

<bean id="web.handler" class="net.sziebert.tutorials.Application">
    <property name="applicationService" ref="applicationService"/>
</bean>
```

I don't have experience to using Spring and Hibernate.
Just using for executing open source examples.

How can I correct these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing

```
org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/MetadataProvider
```

Try adding the following artifact to your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But I didn't notice where can I add to that code.

Comment: Are you using Maven? If not you can download the JAR from [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven/org.hibernate/jars/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.ga.jar)

Comment: Thanks, Now I'm trying to add to lib this !!

Comment: But I have already have hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.jar in my lib

Comment: Ok, is it on the classpath? check that it contains the `MetadataProvider` class

Comment: Oh, There are no MetadataProvider Class. So I notice that it didn't match .jar.

Comment: I think you're mixing up `hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.jar` and  `hibernate-annotations-commons-3.4.0.jar`. Do you have the latter?